# Fastest way of using function on 3D array/matrix to create a new 3D array/matrix

Tags: python, arrays, r

So what I have, or want to create, is a 3D array consisting of different parameters I can then use a function on to create a new 3D array (of same size) with the results from the function. Basically I have something like this (R code) :

```
x <- seq(0,1,0.01)
y <- seq(0,1,0.01)
z <- seq(0,100,0.1)
```

And let's say I have a function that just is just:

```
result = x*data_point + y^2 + z^3
```

In principle I could probably just make three loops, and save it into a array(or something like that), but I would think that would take A LOT of computation time, especially if this step has to be done for several data-points. In this case that would mean approximately 10.000.000 calculations per data-point - and I have about a thousand. So in total around 10 billion calculations.
I understand that in order to get this resulting matrix it will take some time, no matter what, but are there some steps I can do to do it as fast as possible, or is looping the best way ? I also need to be able to go back and say: "I want x = 0.2, y = 0.2, and z = 10 on data-point 5".

A solution in R would be the best, but if it can be done a lot faster in Python, that will work just as well.

Comment: Can you add a few of the data-points to your question? so that we could try your formula?

Comment: I'm not really clear on the context. x,y,z are arrays of evenly spaced numbers. Is result another array? Is result a scalar? Is data_point a scalar? Is data_point a 3-tuple? Which variable is the 3D matrix?

Comment: Hmmm, basically, it's patient data used together with the x-variables to get a set of values. So for each patient/data-point, the x is used to calculate a new value for that specific patient (as seen in the equation). It is however still important to know which x was used. So the data I actually use is not easily converted to something useful here. So basically, if you wanna run a test, you could just make a data_point list saying: data_point <- seq(1,100,1)

Comment: @EternusVia, the reason for the array (in my thinking at least) was that I might be easier/faster to do calculations on an entire array than just by looping. So the array should just consist of 3D matrix of some sort with all the parameters indicated by the different sequences (x, y, and z).  Don't know if that was what oyu were asking for?

Comment: If that's the case, then the result would be a 1D array, not a 3D matrix, correct?

Comment: Are you sure ? There are 3 parameters, so basically x, y, and z. So for example, you go 0.2 in x direction, 0.3 in y-direction, and 30 in the z-direction. The resulting cell should then have (0.2, 0.3, 30). In my head that's a 3D matrix. But maybe you can visualise it in another way. It's just late. So maybe I'm not thinking clearly :)

Comment: I agree that we can put the parameters into a 3D matrix (x,y,z), but when you compute `result[i] = x[i]*data_point[i]+y[i]^2 + z[i]^3` it will give you a 1D array. Just trying to clear up this last point, but once we do I can right you an example code in Python.

Comment: Agreed, as long as they can be identified by the x, y, and z parameters. However, a 1D array would be bad imo. As stated, these 10.000.000 calculations are done for each data_point/patient. So just putting everything in a 1D array would make it a bit hard to find the correct results for each data_point/patient, right ?

Comment: Ahhh. So, for each patient (data_point), you want to compute the result for every possible combination of x,y,z parameter?

Comment: Exactly. So basically a 3d matrix with 10 million entries, for each of the 1000 patients I have.

Comment: What data structures are you familiar with?  Just python lists?  `numpy`?

Comment: I know a lot python, so it shouldn't be any problem whatever comes up. I was just asking in here in order to get the fastest way possible before I started doing 10 different ways in either languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way is to use Numpy's [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) (or [here](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc)).I modified the code from @EternusVia and it is about 14 times faster than his faster version. Avoid for loops wherever possible :)

```
import numpy as np
import time

# number of parameter values and patients
nx=100;
ny=100;
nz=100;
n_data=100;

# dummy data
x = np.linspace(0,1,nx);
y = np.linspace(1,2,ny);
z = np.linspace(2,3,nz);
data = np.linspace(0,100,n_data);

result2 = np.empty((n_data,nx,ny,nz));

# method 2 from @EternusVia
start = time.time()
y2=np.power(y,2);
z3=np.power(z,3);

for l in range(0,n_data):
    for i in range(0,nx):
        for j in range(0,ny):
            result2[l,i,j,:]=x[i]*data[l]+y2[j]+z3[:]
end = time.time()
print(end-start)

# method 3 using Numpy broadcasting
# expand the dimensions of the array depending on where
# they are in the final array
x_bc = x[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
y_bc = y[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis]
z_bc = z[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]
data_bc = data[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]

start = time.time()

# just write the equation, broadcasting will to the rest
# of the magic and calculate the results element-wise
result3 = x_bc * data_bc + np.power(y_bc, 2) + np.power(z_bc, 3)
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
print(np.array_equal(result2,result3))
```

Comment: This is just great. How on earth can it be so much faster ?

Comment: No for loops, at least no visible Python ones :) Only very fast C loops in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to implement your problem in Python; I timed both. Running the first method on my machine for 100^4 elements took about 2 minutes, while the second method took only 4 seconds.

```
import numpy as np
import time

# number of parameter values and patients
nx=100;
ny=100;
nz=100;
n_data=100;

# dummy data
x = np.linspace(0,1,nx);
y = np.linspace(1,2,ny);
z = np.linspace(2,3,nz);
data = np.linspace(0,100,n_data);

result1 = np.empty((n_data,nx,ny,nz));
result2 = np.empty((n_data,nx,ny,nz));

# method 1
start = time.time()
y2=np.power(y,2);
z3=np.power(z,3);

for l in range(0,n_data):
    for i in range(0,nx):
        for j in range(0,ny):
            for k in range(0,nz):
                result1[l,i,j,k] = x[i]*data[l]+y2[j]+z3[k]
end = time.time()
print(end-start)

# method 2
start = time.time()
y2=np.power(y,2);
z3=np.power(z,3);

for l in range(0,n_data):
    for i in range(0,nx):
        for j in range(0,ny):
            result2[l,i,j,:]=x[i]*data[l]+y2[j]+z3[:]
end = time.time()
print(end-start)

print(np.array_equal(result1,result2))
```

Output:

```
133.110018015
4.36485505104
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [`numpy.mgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html)?

```
import numpy as np

x, y, z = np.mgrid[0:1:0.01, 0:1:0.01, 0:100:0.1]
data = np.mgrid[0:100:0.1] # could use np.arange here, but why?

# this will take some time
result = x * data[..., np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] + y**2 + z**3

print(result.shape) # (100, 100, 100, 1000)
```